# Раскрыть все в bootstrap accordion

Tags: jquery, bootstrap

Всем привет.
Гуглил эту тему, нашел решения подобные [этому](http://www.bootply.com/peFUdnwOpZ).
Есть один недочет. Если изначально, в примере по ссылке, раскрыть 2-й блок, потом нажать скрыть все, потом раскрыть все - 2-й блок не раскроется. Я так понимаю, что это из-за селектора при генерируемом классе. Пробовал вариант `jQuery('body').on('click', '.closeall', ...)` - эффект тот же. Убрать часть селектора и оставить `jQuery('.accordion-body')` - тоже не вариант, будут скакать уже раскрытые блоки при раскрытии.
Как можно исправить это?

Answer (score 1):

Достаточно убрать лишнюю часть из селектора и всё заработает.

[Было](http://www.bootply.com/peFUdnwOpZ):

```
$('.closeall').click(function(){
  $('.panel-collapse.in')
    .collapse('hide');
});
$('.openall').click(function(){
  $('.panel-collapse:not(".in")')
    .collapse('show');
});
```

[Стало](http://www.bootply.com/CRBg6YYvVB):

```
$('.closeall').click(function(){
  $('.panel-collapse.in')
    .collapse('hide');
});
$('.openall').click(function(){
  $('.panel-collapse')
    .collapse('show');
});
```

Comment: Проблема только с тем, что при первом нажатии, открыть всё, первый наоборот сворачивается

Comment: @MasterAlex http://www.bootply.com/CQpSkZkQVR

Comment: Вот так лучше :)